# Find the value in Matrix and fill it in a Table or Dataframe

Tags: r

I have two tables. Table 1  need to find the value and fill in Cost col of Table2. Please find the tables as below:

```
**TABLE 1** 
structure(list(X = c("SYD", "MEL", "BRIS"), X1 = c(0.29, 0.4, 
0.46), X3 = c(0.4, 0.29, 0.87), X5 = c(0.46, 0.85, 0.29)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

  
**TABLE 2**     
structure(list(FROM = c("SYD", "SYD", "SYD", "MEL", "MEL"), Weight = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 5L), COST = c(0.29, 0.4, 0.46, 0.4, 0.85)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

 - expected Output:

FROM    Weight  COST
SYD        1    0.29
SYD        3    0.4
SYD        4    0.46
MEL        1    0.4
MEL        5    0.85
```

Currently im checking if Table2_weight is <1.1 then Vlookup "SYD" and getting the value. So I just want to fill cost col in Table 2 based on Table 1. What is the best way to do this in R?

Regards,
Raul

Comment: what is `SYS`? you do not have `SYS` in `table_1`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data in long format after adding the rowname as a new column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  data.frame() %>% #In case if it's a matrix
  tibble::rownames_to_column('From') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -From, names_to = 'To')

#  From  To    value
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 SYD   SYD    0.29
#2 SYD   MEL    0.4 
#3 SYD   BRIS   0.46
#4 MEL   SYD    0.4 
#5 MEL   MEL    0.29
#6 MEL   BRIS   0.85
#7 BRIS  SYD    0.46
#8 BRIS  MEL    0.87
#9 BRIS  BRIS   0.29
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

```
df <- structure(list(SYD = c(0.29, 0.4, 0.46), MEL = c(0.4, 0.29, 0.87
), BRIS = c(0.46, 0.85, 0.29)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("SYD", "MEL", "BRIS"))
```

Comment: Firstly sorry i was not aware of "reproducible format". I was [doing all these stuff Excell and trying to learn R.

Comment: And how do you paste this:                                                                                                  #  From  To    value
#  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#1 SYD   SYD    0.29                    I dont get those # stuff on my Rstudio console.